# body part is not working

Tags: workflow

[image]

This is what workflow I have created and everything is fine no errors I am recieving mail but body part is showing Some Small Box in outlook and The user who is working he is from farm only not out side user and I am working on SharePoint Foundation 2013

Comment: Can you be more clear? The first problem seems to be an small box showed in the received mail. Can you attach a print-screen?
The second one (with the user is not clear), can you explain it better?

Comment: You can't send email to outside email. For that you need to create user and assign the email address to users and then you can send email.
Not Clear: Which small box you have mentioned in the quetion?